# Optimizing Data Migration from 10GB RDB File to Redis Cluster (3 Primary, 3 Replica)

Tags: redis, data-migration, redis-cluster

I'm currently looking to migrate data from a 10GB RDB file to a Redis cluster consisting of 3 primary and 3 replica nodes. I've tried tools like redis-shake and riot, but the migration time takes approximately 1 hour or more.

I'm reaching out for suggestions on tools or methods that could potentially reduce the migration time further to 10-15 mins. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.